# two applications running on the same tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, architecture

When running two applications on the same container

I would like to avoid duplication of code, and separate application responsibility and maintenance to different teams so they can maintain and package independently.

apps will reside in tomcat with different version (team A is responsible to App 1 while Team B is responsible to App 2)

So I would like to know if such scenario is possible:

Two applications running on the same tomcat

They share the same db.

They need to use the same security system (filter on app1 save a token on the session) or spring security.

They will differ only on the context as:

```
http://url:8080/app1     and     http://url:8080/app2
```

Both will register a spring mapping a:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/pathOnApp1/{id}")
@RequestMapping(value="/pathOnApp2/{id}")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Two applications running on the same tomcat

Yes. Deploy two web application archive (war) files.

> They share the same db.
>
> They need to use the same security system (filter on app1 save a token on the session) or spring security.

This is just configuration. You could use the same xml file, properties file or database setup to configure your two (or more) applications. You might use two repositories (one for configuration, one for development). You might use [Apache Zookeeper](http://zookeeper.apache.org/).

Comment: what about spring annotations and configuration

Comment: Is it possible to share spring configuration?

Comment: Yes , they can use same configuration, but they won't use same context, they will generate different application contexts.

Comment: @dogankadriye The question includes *They will differ only on the context as: `http://url:8080/app1` and `http://url:8080/app2`* So, I thought was understood.

Comment: Actually I mean "spring context" , not tomcat application context. We agree about that applications will be different from each other.